# jQuery apply css to parent of class?

Tags: jquery, css

So this is my current jQuery code:

```
$('.aProduct .inner').each(function() {
    var length = $.trim($(this).text()).length;    
    if(length > 20){
        $(this).css("max-height", "20px");
    }
    else {
        $(this).css("background", "blue");
    }
});
```

And it says: if the length of the characters is bigger than 20, apply this CSS to `.aProduct .inner`:

```
$(this).css("max-height", "20px");
```

However, is it possible to give this max-height to the parent of this class? I don't mean just to replace this by `.aProduct .omschrijving`, because then ALL the `.aProduct .omschrijving` would have a max-height of 20. I only want the parent the parent of which the class `.aProduct .omschrijving` has more characters than 20, to have a max-height of 20px.

HTML:

```
<div class="aProductHeader">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <h3>omschrijving</h3>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="aProduct">
    <div class="omschrijving">
        <span class="entry inner">
            Toddler bestek blauw
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This probably sounds really confusing, but I don't know how else to explain this.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/parent or http://api.jquery.com/closest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
if(length > 20){
    $(this).css("max-height", "20px");
}
```

to:

```
if(length > 20){
    $(this).closest('.omschrijving').css("max-height", "20px");
}
```

Comment: Works beautifully. Is there also a solution in case I would also like to style the `.omschrijving` class from the different parent `.aProductHeader`?

Comment: Based on the same criteria of the text length?

Comment: Yes, in the same function.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.aProduct').prev('.aProductHeader').find('.omschrijving').css("max-height", "20px");` will select the `<div class="omschrijving">` from the previous `<div class="aProductHeader">`.

Comment: Wow, this looks a bit more complicated than I thought. I'll have to  look this up a bit more. Thank you for the help!